# unit commitment problem using piecewise-linear approximation become MIQP

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, piecewise

I try to use MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) to calculate the unit commitment problem.
(unit commitment: An optimization problem trying to find the best scheduling of generator)

There are two optimization variables.

Generator power :**P**(continuous variables).
Which line segment on cost curve to use :**BN**(binary variable).
[image],Used to linearize the quadratic cost function of the generator.

Only one line segment can be opened at a time. So there will be a Constraint.
Bn1 + Bn2 + Bn3 <=1

Each line segment will have its own slope and intercept.
I want to calculate the minimum cost.
[image]
This mathematical formula represents the sum of the cost of 1 to H hours.

This is how I code : sum(slope1* **p** * **Bn1**  +intercept1* **Bn1** +slope2* **p** * **Bn2**  +intercept2* **Bn2** +slope3* **p** * **Bn3**  +intercept3* **Bn3**  )

This way, the two optimization variables will be multiplied. Make the problem from MILP become to MIQP.
I want to ask if there is any way can maintain my problem in MILP.
thank you.
ps : i use ibm cplex of python API to solve Optimization problem

Comment: There are quite a few ways to formulate a piecewise linear function. It is easy to find correct formulations using google. This [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/02/piecewise-linear-functions-and.html) (and follow-up posts) presents various methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use piecewise linear in docplex. Let me share the example from the [zoo and bus example in python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')

#after 4 buses, additional buses of a given size are cheaper
f=mdl.piecewise(0, [(0, 0),(4,4)], 0.8)

mdl.minimize(f(nbbus40)*500 + f(nbbus30)*400)

mdl.solve()

mdl.export("c:\\buses.lp")

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
nbBus40  =  0
nbBus30  =  10.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance.Problems that I have solved using your method.

Comment: I encountered another problem using this method. If you have time to help, I will be very grateful. Please refer to : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947896/using-the-piecewise-function-of-the-ibm-cplex-python-api-but-the-problem-cannot
)