# Using the piecewise function of the IBM CPLEX python API, but the problem cannot be solved

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, piecewise, docplex

I try to use MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) to calculate the unit commitment problem. (unit commitment: An optimization problem trying to find the best scheduling of generator)
Because the relationship between generator power and cost is a quadratic function, so I use piecewise function to convert power to cost.

[image]

I modify the answer on this page:
[unit commitment problem using piecewise-linear approximation become MIQP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904604/unit-commitment-problem-using-piecewise-linear-approximation-become-miqp)

The simple program structure is like this:

```py
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')

#after 4 buses, additional buses of a given size are cheaper
f1=mdl.piecewise(0, [(0,0),(4,2000),(10,4400)], 0.8) 
f2=mdl.piecewise(0, [(0,0),(4,1600),(10,3520)], 0.8) 
cost1= f1(nbbus40)
cost2 = f2(nbbus30)

mdl.minimize(cost1+ cost1)
mdl.solve()
mdl.report()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
* model buses solved with 
objective = 3520.000
nbBus40  =  0
nbBus30  =  10.0
```

The answer is perfect but there is no way to apply my example.
I used a piecewise function to formulate a piecewise linear relationship between power and cost, and got a new object (cost1), and then calculated the minimum value of this object.
The following is my actual code(simply):

[image]

`(min1,miny1)`, `(pw1_1,pw1_1y)`,`(pw1_2,pw1_2y)`, `(max1,maxy1)` are the breakpoints on the power-cost curve.

```py
pwl_func_1phase = ucpm.piecewise(
    0,
    [(0,0),(min1,miny1),
     (pw1_1,pw1_1y),
     (pw1_2,pw1_2y),
     (max1,maxy1)
    ],
    0
)

#df_decision_vars_spinning is a dataframe store Optimization variables
df_decision_vars_spinning.at[
    (units,period),
    'variable_cost'
] = pwl_func_1phase(
    df_decision_vars_spinning.at[
        (units,period),
        'production'
    ]
)

total_variable_cost = ucpm.sum(
       (df_decision_vars_spinning.variable_cost))
ucpm.minimize(total_variable_cost )
```

I don’t know what causes this optimization problem can't be solve. Here is my complete code :

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JSKfOf0Vzo3E3FywsxcDdOz4sAwCgOHd?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the model solve with a linear obj? Or even no obj? Note that your obj can be modeled simply with `min cost; cost >= a(i)+b(i)*power` for all linear approximating curves (ie no need tor binary variables).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "problem can't be solve"? Do you get an error? Is it that the model is taking to long to solve? What is the final optimization status?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen  The slope changes with power (slope = piecewise(power) ). If you use a (i) + b (i) * power, the method will cause the problem to become a miqp problem, please refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904604/unit-commitment-problem-using-piecewise-linear-approximation-become-miqp

Comment: @rkersh: problem take very long time to calculate.and finally fail to find a solve.

Comment: I'll explain below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an unlimited edition of CPLEX, your model solves (though very slowly). Here are two ideas to better control what happens in solve()

1. use solve(log_output=True) to print the log: you'll see the gap going down
2. set a mip gap: setting mip gap to 5% stops the solve at 36s

   ucpm.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap = 0.05

   ucpm.solve(log_output=True)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I use your method to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but to illustrate my comment.

Let's say we have as the cost curve

```
cost = α + β⋅power^2
```

Furthermore, we are minimizing cost.

We can approximate using a few linear curves. Here I have drawn a few:

[image]

Let's say each linear curve has the form

```
cost = a(i) + b(i)⋅power
```

for `i=1,...,n` (`n`=number of linear curves).

It is easy to see that is we write:

```
min cost
cost ≥ a(i) + b(i)⋅power   ∀i
```

we have a good approximation for the quadratic cost curve. This is exactly as I said in the comment.

No binary variables were used here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With my knowledge, this method will encounter a problem:How to let the computer know which slope and intercept to use when calculating costs? The way I think of this problem is to set the optimal binary variable Bn. ，cost =sum(slope1* p * Bn1 +intercept1* Bn1 +slope2* p * Bn2 +intercept2* Bn2 +slope3* p * Bn3 +intercept3* Bn3 ) . But as I encountered in the previous problem [1], this will turn the problem into MIQP..[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904604/unit-commitment-problem-using-piecewise-linear-approximation-become-miqp

Comment: All of them need to be obeyed. Of course, usually only one will be binding. You may want to show this to your teacher and he.she will be able to explain it. This is a standard formulation in power system modeling, and you should have this in your toolbox.

Comment: From the log you sent I see your problem has 1800 variables, and the solve failed on exceeding the community edition problem size (1000 variables, 1000 constraints). With an unlimited edition, it solves (though slowly) .

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion in 2020. I only saw it today, so I just reply today